# Using dynamic segments with Ember.js routing

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm having trouble understanding how Ember.js routing works and particularly how to use Dynamic Segments from the route.

For example, if you wanted to grab the token off of a reset password page and use that in a form submission, how would you get the token? The code below attempts to print the token on a page as an intermediate step, but it won't render the TokenView. What am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
window.App = Em.Application.create({});

App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({
    template: Em.Handlebars.compile(
        '<h1>Index</h1>'
    )
});

App.ResetView = Em.View.extend({
    template: Em.Handlebars.compile(
        '<h1>reset view </h1>'
    )
});

App.TokenView = Em.View.extend({
    template: Em.Handlebars.compile(
        '<h1>token view {{token_id}}</h1>'
    )
});

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({

    rootElement:'#content',
    location: 'hash',
    enableLogging: true,

    root: Ember.State.extend({

        index: Ember.ViewState.extend({
            route: '/',
            view: App.IndexView
        }),

        passwordReset: Ember.ViewState.extend({
            route: '/reset',
            view: App.ResetView,

            token: Ember.ViewState.extend({
                route: '/:token_id',
                view: App.TokenView
            })
        })
    })
});

App.router = App.Router.create();
App.initialize(App.router);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the state of the art documentation about `Router` which is in-progress but available @ https://emberjs-staging-new.herokuapp.com/guides/outlets#toc_the-router

Comment: Thanks Mike. That documentation looks much improved, I hadn't found it before.

Comment: I read that page and the details of the mentioned controllers, objects and templates are missing and I keep getting tripped up trying to stub something out for those. Do you have a full example somewhere?

Comment: Here is a full example courtesy of https://github.com/jbrown

http://jsfiddle.net/justinbrown/C7LrM/10/